# How functions return different types depending on the value of the argument object?

Tags: typescript

I've written a function `post`, that thinks of the post's return type based on the `clean` in the `meta`

```
interface MetaConfig<C extends boolean = boolean> {
  clean?: C
}

interface ResponseData<T> {
  code: number
  data: T
  message: string
}

interface Login {
  info: any
}

function post<R = any>(url: string, meta?: MetaConfig<true>): R
function post<R = any>(url: string, meta?: MetaConfig<false>): ResponseData<R>
function post<R = any>(url: string, meta?: MetaConfig): R | ResponseData<R> {
  return {} as R | ResponseData<R>
}

function login1(meta: MetaConfig = { clean: false }) {
  return post<Login>('/login', meta)
}

function login2(meta: MetaConfig = { clean: true }) {
  return post<Login>('/login', meta)
}

// 1. Why the `res` type is `Login` instead of `ResponseData<Login>`?
const res1 = login1() // Hope is `ResponseData<Login>`
const res2 = login2() // Hope is `Login`
const res3 = login1({ clean: false }) // Hope is `ResponseData<Login>`
const res4 = login1({ clean: true }) // Hope is `Login`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Hee9c9bMQ7dAAzCv5SzedIbQK4A8HeuhyPs7nJ+SZ97G-O24eACyn5ntC9+XjKB5mFe9NyfSt8yTIA)

Comment: This looks like two questions in one. Which one is primary?  The first question is that `meta` is of type `MetaConfig<boolean>`, and neither of the two exposed call signaures of `post` takes that type. You can add a third overload that does so, like [this](//tsplay.dev/mAL0XN), but then when you call `post<Login>('/login', meta)` the return type will always be `Login | ResponseData<Login>`; I'm not sure why you'd expect something different for your second question... could you [edit] to restrict this to a single well-defined question and clarify why you expect `Login` for the `login()` call?

Comment: @jcalz Hi, according your link, I found the `res` type is `Login | ResponseData<Login>`, but `clean` is default value `false`, I hope it should be `ResponseData<Login>`

Comment: TypeScript  doesn't synthesize generic call signatures automatically, so the return types of  `login1` and `login2` don't depend on their input types. If you want that you'll need to annotate with a proper generic call signature yourself.  But this is a problem with `login1` and `login2`, not `post()`; so is the question really "How to write a proper function overloading?" or something about how to write `login1` and `login2`?

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment, the generics function is usefull in this case

```
type ResponseData<T> = {
  code: number
  data: T
  message: string
}

type Login = {
  info: any
}

type CleanFlag<T extends boolean> = T extends true ? Login : ResponseData<Login>;

function login<T extends boolean = true>(options?: { clean?: T }): CleanFlag<T> {
  if (options?.clean) {
    return {} as CleanFlag<T>;
  } else {
    return { data: {} as Login } as CleanFlag<T>;
  }
}


// 1. Why the `res` type is `Login` instead of `ResponseData<Login>`?
const res1 = login() // Hope is `ResponseData<Login>`
const res3 = login({ clean: false }) // Hope is `ResponseData<Login>`
const res4 = login({ clean: true }) // Hope is `Login`
```